# How to remove whitespaces from source of posts created through WordPress Gutenberg editor

Tags: block-editor

[image: see line 147,148,149 151,152,153]
my understanding is that empty lines are created when Gutenberg removes the block comment. so how can i remove this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? When using the block editor, you still use `the_content()` within the theme, so you could filter that output. Or: why worry and use an existing method such as HTML minifaction that almost all caching plugins and services such as Cloudflare offer.

Comment: thanks @keno for your response, I just wanted to remove empty lines from the source but did not want to minify html

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_white_space( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $content );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_white_space' );
```

I got a working solution with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709669/how-do-i-remove-blank-lines-from-text-in-php